# If a dwarf barbarian wears heavy armor how fast do they move?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, barbarian, dwarf

Quoted from d20:

> Base Speed: (Slow and Steady) Dwarves have a base speed of 20 feet,
>   but their speed is never modified by armor or encumbrance.

and

> A barbarian’s land speed is faster than the norm for her race by +10
>   feet. This benefit applies only when he is wearing no armor, light
>   armor, or medium armor, and not carrying a heavy load. Apply this
>   bonus before modifying the barbarian’s speed because of any load
>   carried or armor worn. This bonus stacks with any other bonuses to the
>   barbarian’s land speed.

So a dwarf can never be slowed by any kind of armor, but barbarians lose the +10 feet of movement when wearing heavy armor.

Which takes priority over the other?

Answer (score 21):

They do not conflict.

The dwarf's base speed is never modified by armor or encumbrance. Their base speed is 20.

The barbarian gains a bonus to base speed when not wearing heavy armor (and not carrying a heavy load). Once they wear heavy armor (or carry a heavy load), the class feature no longer has its conditions met, and thus does not provide the bonus, regardless of being a dwarf or not.

Therefore, as a dwarf barbarian, when wearing non-heavy armor and not carrying a heavy load, your base speed is 30, and is not affected by armor or encumbrance. When wearing heavy armor or carrying a heavy load, your base speed is 20, and is still not affected by encumbrance or armor.

Comment: I would suggest a different phrasing to "they stop benefiting" e.g. "the benefit is not triggered at all" - want to avoid the implication that wearing heavy armour is removing any bonus (because then it may look like the dwarven racial feature is triggered).

Comment: Good point, Does this edit work?